# @Async with outstream and thread.sleep method

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

A simple question on @Async annotation.

For example: A method is @Async annotated and it contains thread.sleep for few seconds.
And after the sleep, their is a outStream.println. Then what is the result.

I have used ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as executor

I just want to know as i have tried above with a sleep of 5 seconds, but getting outStream.println in fraction of second. So I just want to understand if this is how Async annotation works i.e., if it has given the instant response and thread.sleep is executed by other thread.

Comment: Show us your method. I'm not sure I understand the behavior you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your method is like this

```
@Async
public void foo() {
    sleep(5000L);
    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

This won't tell you anything as the 5sec wait is in another thread anyway. However if you have something like this

```
public void bar() {
    myService.foo();
    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

Then if you get Hello World in "a fraction of second", it means that the invocation of foo has been indeed done asynchronously.

When you invoke a method with `@Async` the method invocation is wrapped in a `Callable` and that instance is passed to the executor service using the `submit` method.

If the executor cannot process the method execution, you'll get a `TaskRejectedException`. For instance, if your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` has a pool size of 2 threads and a queue size of 0, the third invocation of the `foo` method will fail with a `TaskRejectedException` if the pool threads are still busy processing the two first invocations.